# Rearranging columns with NAs

Tags: r

Sorry guys,

this is probably a silly question but I do not manage to find a quick solution to solve this issue.

I have a dataframe of this form indicating the number of components of households and gender of each member

```
Familyid  Gender_1 Gender_2 Gender_3 Gender_4  Ncomponent
1         1        NA       NA       NA        1
2         NA       1        NA       NA        1
3         1        2        NA       NA        2
4         1        NA       2        NA        2
5         NA       1        2        NA        2
6         2        NA       NA       1         2
```

I would like to collect this info just in two columns in the following way.

```
Familyid  Gender_member1   Gender_member2   Ncomponent
1         1                NA               1
2         1                NA               1
3         1                2                2
4         1                2                2
5         1                2                2
6         2                1                2
```

In other words I want to create a column indicating gender of member 1, regardless in which column he/she is located in my original dataframe, and a different one indicating gender of the second family member, whenever this latter exists.

Can anyone helping me out with this?

Marco

Comment: Basically you would like to remove NAs from Gender_1-4 and return whatever is left in existing order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed `NA`s for `Gender_x` columns.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "Familyid  Gender_1 Gender_2 Gender_3 Gender_4  Ncomponent
1         1        NA       NA       NA        1
2         NA       1        NA       NA        1
3         1        2        NA       NA        2
4         1        NA       2        NA        2
5         NA       1        2        NA        2
6         2        NA       NA       1         2",
                 header = TRUE)
xy

fetch.gender <- grepl("^Gender_\\d{1}$", names(xy))
out <- apply(xy[, fetch.gender], MARGIN = 1, FUN = na.omit)
out <- do.call(rbind, out)
names(out) <- c("Gender_member1", "Gender_member2")

data.frame(Familyid = xy$Familyid, out, Ncomponent = xy$Ncomponent)

  Familyid Gender_1 Gender_2 Ncomponent
1        1        1        1          1
2        2        1        1          1
3        3        1        2          2
4        4        1        2          2
5        5        1        2          2
6        6        2        1          2
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys you helped me solving this! And sorry if there was another very similar question to mine.